# Why the render h function cannot use component name directly to render in Vue3.x as Vue2.x?

Tags: vuejs3

In `Vue2.x`, the code can work;

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.component('helloworld', {
  render(h) {
    return h('div', 'this is helloworld');
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h('helloworld')
});
```

But in `Vue3.x` code like below, it can not work;

```
import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
const app = createApp({
    render: () => h('helloworld')
});
app.component("helloworld", {
    render() {
      return h('div', 'this is helloworld');
    }
});
```

why `h('helloworld')` can work in `vue2`, but cannot work in `vue3.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `resolveComponent` to handle your component name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using it like this? 
Within the setup, as mentioned [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/render-function-api.html#_3-x-syntax-2) in their doc

```
import { h, reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup(props, { slots, attrs, emit }) {
    const state = reactive({
      count: 0
    })

    function increment() {
      state.count++
    }

    // return the render function
    return () =>
      h(
        'div',
        {
          onClick: increment
        },
        state.count
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because the component doesn't used in the "h" function.
The h() called is separately to your app which create by creatApp.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

In Vue 3, you have to use `resolveComponent()` instead of the component string directly. Pop it into a variable and use it as follows

```
import {createApp, h, resolveComponent} from 'vue';
import helloWorldComponent from './components/helloWorld.vue'

const app = createApp({
  components: {
    'helloWorld': helloWorldComponent,
  },
  render: () => {
    const component = resolveComponent('helloWorld');
    return h(component)
  }
});
```

Comment: helloWorldComponent is not used in your answer

Comment: @walox you're right! fixed